# Choosing values dependent on other column values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a data file that looks like:

```
3       24.5
3       23.7
3       21.87
3       24.3
3       10.45
6       11.2
6       22.5
6       20.95
```

I want to use the data in the second column but only those that have a value of 3 in the first column. My code currently grabs all numbers that are in the second column when I only want the ones that have a corresponding '3' values alongside them.
What should I add to the code to make this distinction?
Here's my code:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ") + '.csv'
filepath = '/home/david/Desktop/' + filename

data = np.genfromtxt(filepath, delimiter=',',skip_header=1, dtype=float)

rownum = input("Enter row number to use: ")
line = [row[rownum] for row in data]
binw = input("Enter bin width: ")
bins=arange(int(min(line)-1), int(max(line)+1), binw)

pyplot.hist(line, bins=bins, alpha=0.5, color='g')

pyplot.show()
```

I'm using row 5 as the data that has to be analyzed and plotted. However, row 3 has the '3' and the '6' values that I want python to filter for me.

Comment: If `data` is a `numpy` array with your data, then `data[data[:,0] == 3][:,1]` will give you the 2nd column of data where the first column is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't you actually mean columns instead of rows?

After you read the data using `np.genfromtxt`, which returns numpy array, you can use `numpy.where` to select only those rows which contain certain value in a specific column. If column 3 contains the data which should be used for filtering, then first do the following

```
data = data[np.where(data[:,target_column] == target_value)]
```

This will select all rows whose value at position `target_column` is `target_value`. With your values, the code becomes

```
data = data[np.where(data[:,3] == 3)]
```

After this, you can select the column which contains the data to be plotted by simply writing

```
# I'm renaming rownum to colnum
line = data[:,colnum]
```

This should give a fair starting point.

Comment: Thanks! And yes I do. Sorry for the mixup